# Remove commas from numbers in a text file

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove commas from numbers within a text file that is being read in. I am unable to do so.

This is how I am reading in my data:

```
def fileLoader(file):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    with open(file) as fin:
        chk_lst = next(fin).split()
        is_h = not any(v[0].isdecimal() for v in chk_lst)
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=(0, 1)[is_h])], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

The current code output (error) reads:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,498,300153,90023,90066,30079,60042,20011,60083,771131,000497,400715,00085,40028,40081,500153,900454,00024,5008,0003,000'

TypeError: Could not convert 3,498,300153,90023,90066,30079,60042,20011,60083,771131,000497,400715,00085,40028,40081,500153,900454,00024,5008,0003,000 to numeric
```

A sample of the file I am trying to read in looks like this:

```
TEST    3,498,300   2.600
ABC     153,900     2.500
CBA     23,900      2.250
NYT     66,300      2.250
```

My end result should look like:

```
TEST    3498300     2.600
ABC     153900      2.500
CBA     23900       2.250
NYT     66300       2.250
```

Comment: Could you add the current (unwanted) output of your code in the question?

Comment: @EnderLook added

Comment: Take a look at the arguments `thousands` and `decimal` in `pd.read_csv`. For example you need `pd.read_csv(filename, thousands=',' , decimal='.')` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the text file you are reading is a csv file. What you can do is to use the thousands argument built in the pd.read_csv.

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_csv(file, sep='\s+', header=None, skiprows=(0, 1)[is_h])], 
                axis=0, 
                ignore_index=True, 
                thousands=',')
```

Comment: This works -> thousands=','. Life saver- thank you!

Comment: @ravecoder one question... if i want to remove all the commas in all text files in one directory, how can i do that? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the comma's with "" (an empty string)

```
example = "TEST    3,498,300   2.600"
example  = example.replace(",", "")
print(a)
```

The code above prints

```
TEST    3498300   2.600
```

Comment: In reality my program should be reading 100k+ files a day so I wasn't sure if that would be the most efficient

Answer (score 0):

Use the following (note I didnt use headers for now)

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s+', header=None, thousands=',')

print(df)
      0        1     2
0  TEST  3498300  2.60
1   ABC   153900  2.50
2   CBA    23900  2.25
3   NYT    66300  2.25
```

Comment: If I have some files I'm reading in that have comma while others I do that don't. How would I check to see if data.txt has commas in them before applying thousands=','

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Thimo1, starting with the example you gave:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['TEST',    '3,498,300',   "2.600"],
                  ['ABC',     '153,900',     '2.500'],
                  ['CBA',     '23,900',      '2.250'],
                  ['NYT',     '66,300',      '2.250']])
```

A pandas-centric way would be:

```
df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].str.replace(',','')
```

This will give you:

```
Out[29]: 
      0        1      2
0  TEST  3498300  2.600
1   ABC   153900  2.500
2   CBA    23900  2.250
3   NYT    66300  2.250
```

I assume though you prefer the latter two columns are not strings so you could then:

```
df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1].astype(int)
df.iloc[:,2] = df.iloc[:,2].astype(float)
```